# Wiping out embedded activemq data during testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm actively using `ActiveMQ` in my project. Although production use standalone `ActiveMQ` instance my tests require embedded `ActiveMQ` instance. After execution of particular test method `ActiveMQ` holds unprocessed messages in queues. I'd like to wipe out `ActiveMQ` instance after each test. I tried to use `JMX` to connect to local `ActiveMQ` instance and wipe out queues, but it's heavy-weight solution. Could anyone suggest me something more lightweight?

Answer (score 4):

just turn off broker persistence when you define the broker URL for your unit tests

```
vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
```

Answer (score 3):

ActiveMQ has an option to delete all message on startup, if you use the XML way of configuring ActiveMQ broker, you can set it on the < activemq > tag,

```
<activemq:broker .... deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true">

   ...
</activemq:broker>
```

Another approach could be to use unique data directories per unit test which is what we do when unit testing camel-jms component with embedded ActiveMQ broker. We have a helper class that setup ActiveMQ for us, depending on we needed persistent queues or not

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=blob;f=components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/CamelJmsTestHelper.java;h=8c81f3e2bed738a75841988fd1239f54a100cd89;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks Claus, however I doubt ActiveMQ will restart between tests. I'll try your another approach.

Comment: Your unit tests should start and stop the broker in the Before and After methods.  This allows you to control the state of the broker between runs.  Look at the ActiveMQ unit tests for inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to purge the queue. There are several options for that.

https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-purge-a-queue.html

from the link

> "You can use the Web Console to view queues, add/remove queues, purge queues or delete/forward individual messages. Another option is to use JMX to browse the queues and call the purge() method on the QueueViewMBean. You could also delete the queue via removeQueue(String) or removeTopic(String) methods on the BrokerViewMBean. You can also do it programmatically"

The link describes each option in details

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.